How the modified Bernoulli numbers relate to the ordinary Bernoulli numbers
The modified Bernoulli numbers are defined as the numbers $b_k$ whose generating series is
$$\frac 1 2\log\left(\frac{\sinh \frac t 2}{\frac t 2}\right) = \sum_k b_k t^k.$$
(I use a slightly different convention than the linked mathworld article, since $\sinh x = \frac 1 2(e^x - e^{-x})$. This leads to $b_0 = 0$ in my convention. All other modified Bernoulli numbers are the same by the functional equation of $\log$.)
It is claimed that for $n \geq 1$
$$b_n = \frac{B_n}{2n \cdot n!}, \tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
where $B_n$ is the ordinary Bernoulli number defined by the generating function $\sum_n B_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x}{e^x-1}$. I would like to understand why \eqref{eq:1} holds.
I guess the connection to the Bernoulli numbers comes from
$$\frac x {\sinh x} = 1 + \sum_{k \geq 1} (2-2^k)B_k \frac{x^k}{k!},\tag{2}\label{eq:2}$$
which I assume as given. Using the power series expansion $\log(1+x) = \sum_k \frac{(-1)^{k+1}} k x^k$ one gets
$$\sum_k b_k t^k =  \sum_k \frac{(-1)^{k}} {2k} \left(\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2-2^n}{2^n} B_n \frac {t^n}{n!}\right)^k,$$
but expanding further gets messy and I don't see how to continue. Is that the correct way to show \eqref{eq:1}, or is there something more elegant?

Here is how this works without taking powers of power series. Set
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{B_k}{2k \cdot k!} z^k,$$
so that
$$f'(z) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{B_k}{2k!} z^{k-1} = \frac 1 {2z} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} z^k = \frac{1}{2z} \left(\frac{z}{e^z-1} -1 + \frac 1 2 z\right) = \frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 {e^z-1} + \frac 1 2- \frac 1 z\right).$$
Hence it suffices to show
$$\frac d {dz} \log\left(\frac{\sinh(z/2)}{z/2}\right) = \frac{1}{e^z-1} + \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 z,$$
which can be done by standard calculus.
